# Android, issues with custom listview

Tags: android

I'm using a custom listview I found here:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/layout/linear_layout_9.html

Seems to be valid in Eclipse, and looks good in the preview tab. It's just a listview that has a button on the bottom. So i've added it as R.layout.buttonlist

```
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/testbutton"
        android:text="@string/hello" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_above="@id/testbutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Unfortunately when I run it, i get a pop up window that says Android has closed unexpecitdly:

```
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.buttonlist , data));
```

When I try using a built in list view:

```
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , data));
```

everything works fine. I dont see any errors or warnings in logcat, so I'm not sure how to pinpoint the problem. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Edit: adding activity

```
public class TestActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
       data.add("hello");
       data.add("world");
        setContentView(R.layout.buttonlist);
        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , data));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoofamon, I would like to correct you here. You are not creating a custom ListView but a custom layout with a ListView. Also, I believe that you have not completely understood what the setListAdapter is doing here.

This line that you have is telling the listview to consume '**android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1**' as the content of its layout. This layout comes pre-defined in the Android SDK. It would just contain text in each item of a listview. The third attribute '**data**' indicates the content of each listview item.

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , data));
```

So, as Mike L. has suggested, if your intent is to have a listview with only text (having the default format), then the line above would serve the purpose well. You can set '**R.layout.buttonlist**' as the layout of your activity using

```
setContentView(R.layout.buttonlist);
```

However, if you are planning to include additional content in the listview (read images) or want to change the styling of the text, you would have to define a custom layout for the listview. We can direct you to appropriate sources if you want to know how that can be done.

**EDIT**: *A possible way of loading data into a normal ListView*

**TestActivity.java**

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.buttonlist);

      List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
      data.add("hello");
      data.add("world");


      ListView mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

      mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , data));

   }
}
```

**buttonlist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <Button 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/testbutton"
    android:text="@string/hello" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

   <ListView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/testbutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it should look like on the emulator: [image: ListView]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately when I try setContentView(R.layout.buttonlist); as you suggest I still get the same error. I've edited my origional post to include the activity incase that is useful. Even if your proposed method works, I'm left wondering how I can add data to this?

Comment: Please look at the edit! If there is no specific reason why you are extending ListActivity, then I recommend extending an Activity since the differences among the two aren't significant

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have a listview in the layout of an adapter. The passed in layout should just describe a row in the listview. So buttonlist should just contain the xml for the button. The listview needs to be in a separate layout file. If this is a list activity then you don't need another layout file, just call setListAdapter like you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your R.layout.buttonlist to fill up your listview,you can do it as follows(your TestActivity should extend Activity,not ListActivity):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buttonlist);

    String data[]=new String[]{"Item_1","Item_2","Item_3"}
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.testbutton);
    ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayAdapter aa=new ArrayAdapter(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    lv.setAdapter(aa);

    //Your code...
}
```

Now if you want to create custom listitem to be displayed in the listview,then you need to do like this:

1. Create your custom listitem xml file.

   Ex: custom_listitem.xml

   ```
   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/icon"
       />
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:id="@+id/text"
       />
   ```
2. Create custom ArrayAdapter:

   Ex. CustomArrayAdapter.class

   ```
   public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

   String[] array;
   LayoutInflater mInflater;

   public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
           String[] objects)
   {
       super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
       array=objects;
       mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
   {       
       final ViewHolder holder;

       if(convertView==null)
       {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listitem, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.text=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.img=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
       }
       else
               holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

       holder.text.setText(array[position]);

       if(position==0)
           holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
       else if(position==1)
           holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
       else if(position==2)
           holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3);

       return convertView;
   }

   static class ViewHolder
   {
       TextView text;
       ImageView img;
   }
   }
   ```
3. Use this custom adapter class in your main activity to fill up listview:

   Be sure,this main activity extends Activity and not ListActivity

   ```
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   context=getApplicationContext();
   lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

   CustomArrayAdapter aa=new CustomArrayAdapter(context,R.layout.custom_listitem, new String[]{"item_1","item_2","item_3"});

   lv.setAdapter(aa);

              // other lines of code
              .
              . 
              .
   ```